# Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir 'src/app/test.html'

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs

I have this recursive function to walk the directory tree to get all the files.  Not sure why fs.stat(path).isDirectory() is failing sometime on different file when the the script is run.  When the script is run multiple times, the result is inconsistent:
-Sometime when a path is a directory, fs.stat(path).isDirectory() returns false.  -Other times when a path is a file, fs.stat(path).isDirectory() returns true.  And -Sometime the script runs without errors.

```
const filesInDir$ = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(fs.readdir)
const statFile$ = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(fs.stat)

const getFiles = (dir = '') => {
  const file$ = filesInDir$(dir)
    .flatMap(f$ => f$)
    .filter(file => file.indexOf('.spec') < 0)
  const isDir$ = file$
    .flatMap(file => statFile$(`${dir}/${file}`))
    .map(f2 => {return {isDir: f2.isDirectory(), timestamp: 
 f2.mtime.getTime(), size: f2.size}});
  return file$
    .zip(isDir$, (file, obj) => {
      console.log('file', file, obj, dir)
      return ({file, obj})
    })
    .map(f => {
      if(f.obj.isDir || f.file.indexOf('.') < 0) {
        console.log('***dir', dir, f.file, f.obj.isDir)
        return getFiles(`${dir}/${f.file}`)
      } else if(f.file.indexOf('.') >= 0) {
        return Rx.Observable.of({dir: dir, name: f.file, timestamp: f.obj.timestamp, size: f.obj.size});
      }
    }).flatMap(fobj => fobj)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely down to `flatMap` not preserving the order of the calls. The notifications from `isDir$` won't necessarily come out in an order that corresponds to those from `file$`; they will come out in the order in which they become available.

Use `concatMap` to ensure the order will be correct:

```js
const isDir$ = file$
  .concatMap(file => statFile$(`${dir}/${file}`))
  .map(f2 => ({
    isDir: f2.isDirectory(),
    timestamp: f2.mtime.getTime(),
    size: f2.size
  }));
```